# Something in areapl() function that I can't understand in R

Tags: r, polygon, area

I'm trying to learn how to calculate an area using some of the functions in R packages. `areapl()` is the first one that I found in `splancs` package. There is one example at the end of the help file:

```
x <- c(1,0,0,1,1,1,1,3,3,1)
y <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,-1,-1,0,0)
m <- cbind(x, y)
plot(m, type="b")
areapl(m)
areapl(m[1:5,])
areapl(m[6:10,])
```

Obviously the answers of `areapl(m[1:5,])` and `areapl(m[6:10,])` are what we expected however when I try this `areapl(m)` it gives me 1 as the answer. What I expected was the sum of `areapl(m[1:5,])` and `areapl(m[6:10,])` which should be 3 rather than the difference of the two areas.

Can anyone help me understand how this function works?

Much appreciate for the help.

Comment: From `?areapl` - "Calculate area of polygon. If the polygon is **self-intersecting**, the area will **not** be correct.

Comment: By self-intersecting do you mean overlap? I have also tried other options as long as there are two areas in one plot the result won't be right.

Comment: it's the fact that the polygon doubles back on itself. For instance, you can define the same shape as you have that gives an area of `3` like: `x <- c(1,0,0,1,1  ,3, 3, 1,1);y <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,-1,-1,0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must preserve the order (clockwise or counter-clockwise) of the points you are giving. Try:

```
   x[6:10]<-x[10:6]
   y[6:10]<-y[10:6]
   m <- cbind(x, y)
   areapl(m)
```

I don't have `splancs` installed and didn't test it. However, I tested it with other polygon libraries, so I'm pretty sure that that is the issue. You provided the points of the first polygon clockwise and the points of the second one counter-clockwise. Try yo be coherent and you should be fine.